# Cocos2d sprites not working on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

My game works fine in the simulator but it has probems with the sprites on the device. A line like this will give an error:

```
img = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"img.png"];
```

Then:

```
Assertion failure in -[CCSprite initWithTexture:rect:], /Users/newuser/Documents/Uni/libs/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:171
```

Someone suggested that some devices can't handle spritesheets bigger than 1024x1024, is this true? Because mine is 1024x2048, but it's a lot of effort to make 2 spritesheets so I was looking for confirmation of this first?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a lot of effort. In Photoshop just assign two slices at half the height and when you export to image it will cut them automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devices older than the 3GS (iPhone 3G, iPod 1 and 2) are limited to 1024 * 1024 textures. The newer devices can use upto 2048 * 2048

Comment: Heh yeah my old 3G absolutely CHOKES on my current in development game.